# How to improve the result of the TextRecognize?

Tags: image

I have some words want to recognize.
For example,I have this image:

[image]

```
Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFYhS.png"] // TextRecognize
```

But the result is wrong.

```
Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFYhS.png"] // TextRecognize[ImageResize[#, Scaled[2]]] &
```

Enlarging the image isn't help to the quality of recognized text.

So how to resolve this problem?

Comment: This almost works: `TextRecognize@WienerFilter[#, 2] &@ImageResize[#, Scaled[2]] &@
 Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/FFYhS.png"]`. It unfortunately mistakes 0 for U.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [corey979's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127084/how-to-improve-the-result-of-the-textrecognize#comment343786_127084) I found this solution:

```
TextRecognize@
GaussianFilter[#, 4] &@
ImageResize[#, Scaled[3]] &@
ImagePad[#, 4, White] &@
Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFYhS.png"]
```

The `GaussianFilter` is important to get rid of the "singular" connection of the bars of the `0`s. I also added some padding, so that the `GaussianFilter` can extend the letters outwards.

Comment: At the same moment I found `TextRecognize @ GaussianFilter[#, 4] & @ ImageResize[#, Scaled[3]] & @ 
 Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/FFYhS.png"]` - it doesn't need `ImagePad`.

Comment: @DPF on Windows 10 with Mathematica 11 I get HXMSY8201620001, which is still slightly wrong. I think that TextRecognize, being based on Tesseract, is quite limited. Tesseract has some deep problems, see e.g. [this not recognized bug report](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/305#issuecomment-223522801).

Comment: @RolfMertig Interesting. You could try to add a `Binarize` after the `GaussianFilter` and play with the Gauss range. Of course, some knowledge about the structure of the String would help a lot.